# Я делаю сайт, на котором использую mysql, но возникли проблемы с переадресацией на php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Я использую MAMP, mysql, php и html.
Проблема в чем: строка `header("Location: /");` почему-то не работает, и на сайте мне выдает такую ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я все проверил, MAMP запущен, а ошибок в коде вроде бы нету. Помогите пожалуйста.

вот php код:

```
<?php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(mb_strlen($login) < 2 || mb_strlen($login) > 90) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
} else if(mb_strlen($name) < 2 || mb_strlen($name) > 90) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина имени";
    exit();
} else if(mb_strlen($pass) < 8 || mb_strlen($pass) > 20) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина пароля (8-20)";
    exit();
}

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register-bd');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users2` (`login`, `pass`, `name`) VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");

$mysql->close()

header("Location: /");
?>
```

по видео-уроку который я смотрел, меня должно было перенести на index.html, но это не произошло

Comment: 1. Смотреть error.log
2. Полный код вашего приложения мы за вас должны придумать?

Comment: перед
header("Location: /");
надеюсь никаких echo / print_r 
не объявлено?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добавил php код

Comment: вы комментарии читайте. иногда. все проблемы большинства людей - от невнимательности.
но если лень..
то прочитайте как работает header()

Comment: посмотрел error.log. Там пишет что  ошибка на стороне сервера. Тоесть 500. Никаких echo/print_r тоже нету. Спасибо, сейчас пойду читать как работает header.

Сейчас более подробно опишу проблему:
 Я делаю регистрацию. Все работает кроме переадресации с check.php на index.html. Пересмотрел кучу роликов как сделать переадресацию на php, но ничего не помогло. Также писал header("Location: index.html"); , но тоже не работает. Добавлю, что check.php и index.html находяться в одной папке, на одном уровне.

Answer (score 1):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка в самом коде, а именно в строке `$mysql->close()`